# How to handle values in Service request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**response.json.response:**

```
    {
 "servicetype":"",
"functiontype":"",
"statuscode":"0",
"statusmessage":"Success",
"data":    [{"graphtype":"headcountgraph",
"xlabel":"cityLevelData",
"ylabel":"count",
"s1":"contact",
"s2":"User",
    "data":
["Total enquiries: 36,
 contacts: 36",
[{"x":"AbtStreet","s1":"36","s2":"36"}]]}]}
```

I need to refer the array X in my code as Abtstreet.

```
var data = response.json.response.data[0].data[0];
                        console.log('data: '+JSON.stringify(data[]));
```

where I get value as Total Enquirers , Contacts but how to get value of x from data . Need assistance.

Comment: there are several `data` keys in that json, could you be more specific?

Comment: If `response` is the entire object you have included in your question. Then `x` would be `response.data[0].data[1].x`. Of course you need to check for constraints like it `data[1]` is indeed an array or not and other such conditions for top level elements too.

Comment: angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined . This error I get . Even I tried same format.

Answer (score 0):

Here If you want to access Array of `x`. then you should try this:

```
var data = response.json.response.data[0].data[1][0];
console.log('data: '+JSON.stringify(data));`

output: data: {"x":"AbtStreet","s1":"36","s2":"36"}
```

But if you want to get value of `x` only then you should try this:

```
var data = response.json.response.data[0].data[1][0].x;
console.log('data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
output: data: "AbtStreet"
```

Comment: Hi , I get this error . angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined . Even I tried the same .

Comment: For data, that you have provided in question; it is working fine. I think you are testing it for different data.

Comment: No I am trying to fetch the Abt street only. But its not reading and it gives type error.